# How to json_encode associative php array to [{x: key1, y: value1}, {x: key2, y: value2}, ...]?

Tags: php, arrays, json, chart.js

I want to display two line charts with chart.js in one chart. Because some x-values are not identical (some are missing in one dataset, some in the other) I need the data for both datasets in this format:

```
[{x: "key1", y: value1}, 
{x: "key2", y: value2}, 
{x: "key3", y: value3}, 
... 
{x: "key_n", y: value_n}]
```

My starting point are two php arrays for each dataset (fetched from a mysql database). The json encoded output of the first array is:

```
["2019-06-25","2019-06-26","2019-06-27","2019-06-28","2019-06-29","2019-06-30","2019-07-01"]
```

The json encoded output of the second array is:

```
[3.304,3.24,3.137,3.232,3.279,3.298,3.307]
```

Chart.js does expect this format:

```
[{x: "2019-06-25", y: 3.304}, 
{x: "2019-06-26", y: 3.24}, 
{x: "2019-06-27", y: 3.137}, 
{x: "2019-06-28", y: 3.232}, 
{x: "2019-06-29", y: 3.279}, 
{x: "2019-06-30", y: 3.298}, 
{x: "2019-07-01, y: 3.307}]
```

I've tried it this way:

```
$combined = array_combine($leonie_created_at, $weight_leonie);

foreach( $combined as $key=>$val ) {
      $result .= '{' . 'x: ' . $key . ', y: ' . $val . '}';
}
```

But the json encoded result is

```
 "{x: 2019-06-25, y: 3.304}{x: 2019-06-26, y: 3.24}{x: 2019-06-27, y: 3.137}{x: 2019-06-28, y: 3.232}{x: 2019-06-29, y: 3.279}{x: 2019-06-30, y: 3.298}{x: 2019-07-01, y: 3.307}{x: 2019-07-02, y: 3.18}"
```

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: This should be a simple `for` loop that iterates over both arrays and combines the current elements into an array that it pushes onto the final result.

Comment: @Barmar Magento StackExchange should have this comment :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `foreach` loop with `json_encode`

```
$r  = [];
foreach($a1 as $k => $v){
  $r[] = ['x' => $a1[$k], 'y' => $a2[$k]];
}
echo json_encode($r);
```

https://3v4l.org/1pOhV

Comment: That's perfect, Rakesh! Thank you so much! It works as expected. If you are interested for the result, take a look: https://dashboard.frickelpiet.de/pages/catscale_overview.php